# No sound. Pulseaudio broken ( Fedora )

Tags: fedora, audio, pulseaudio

I uploaded a fedora yesterday. Everything worked just fine. But today, there is no sound. There's no sound. I tried things about Purseaudio, but it didn't work. How can I fix ?

( W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
)

Comment: Curious about this one, did you try adding root to a pulse-access group? _All users that need access to PulseAudio have to be in the pulse-access group_ [PulseAudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide/)

Comment: try `systemctl --user status pulseaudio`

Comment: @nikgnomic Output: Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Fri 2019-08-02 09:42:32 +03; 15min ago
           └─ ConditionUser=!root was not met

Answer (score 0):

I followed this suggestion and it brought back audio and video.

```bsh
dnf install https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm

dnf groupupdate multimedia --setop=”install_weak_deps=False” --exclude=PackageKit-gstreamer-plugin --allowerasing
```

I forgot where I copied this from, but great many thank yous to the person who submitted this fix.

Comment: If you could [edit] your answer and provide the link, that might be useful.